# Рекуррентные соотношения

Tags: c#, алгоритм, рекуррентность

Найти первый элемент, больший K, последовательностей {x} и {y}, определяемых рекуррентными соотношениями:

[image: рекуррентные соотношения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы уже начали писать код? Покажите.

Comment: Нет, так как совсем не могу понять задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша задача - задать две переменные с начальными значениями

```
x = 1
y = 0
```

Затем запускаете цикл (бесконечный), в котором рассчитываете новые значения

```
tempx = x  //запомним старое значение
x = x + 2*y  
y = y - 2*tempx
```

и проверяете, не стали ли значения больше, чем K. Если да, то останавливаете цикл, и выводите то, что нужно

Answer (score 1):

Можно и [без временной переменной](https://ideone.com/PKnljd) :)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 1, y = 0;
    int K = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    for(;;)
    {
        x += 2 * y;
        y = 5 * y - 2 * x;
        if (x > K || y > K) break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("x = " + x + "  y = " + y);
}
```